# Eclipse RCP Splash Screen

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I'm involved in a project that is attempting to use the Eclipse RCP splash screen to gather user credentials, language, etc. If this screen loses focus, it is not available (under Windows at least) through the ALt-Tab functionality, and can only be found by minimizing all other windows and uncovering it. Any way of having this screen allow itself to be activated in this way? They're avoiding creating an intermediate screen, for reasons unknown at this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it might be time to examine those unknown reasons.  Even eclipse doesn't use the splash screen in this way.  If it needs to prompt for information, it opens a new dialog to ask for it.

Good luck.

**[Edit]**  I stand corrected.  [This thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg26519.html) seems to have a solution to this.  Good luck, I'm no SWT/RCP guru.

Answer (score 2):

See [this page](http://tom-eclipse-dev.blogspot.com/2007/06/splash-screen-and-threads.html). From one of the comments:

> The splash screen window is created natively with the extended window style WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW which makes it not appear in the task bar. This corresponds to the SWT constant SWT.TOOL.

I don't know if it's possible to change the window style after it is created on Windows. You can always drop down to JNI if that's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own implementation of AbstractSplashHandler.
When creating the shell, don't use the SWT.TOOL style.
The shell will be accessible through the windows task bar.